# How do I center this horizontal line in equation mode?

Tags: equations, amsmath, mathtools

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \ch{ADP(aq) + P_i (aq) -> ATP(aq) + H2O (l)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (1)=30.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}} \\
    \ch{ADP(aq) + H2O (l) -> AMP(aq) + P_i (aq)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (2)=-28.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}} \\[-\jot]
    \mathclap{\rule{12cm}{0.4pt}}\\
    \ch{2 ADP(aq) -> AMP(aq) + ATP(aq)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (3)=2.0\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can explain why it doesn't center: there's an implicit `&` at the end of that line, so your `\rule` is centered at the `&` of the other lines.  You can shift it left a bit by swapping all `&` and `\qquad`, and a bit more left by `\hspace`ing after the `\rule`.  But that's a bit trial and error, so I don't know if it's what you really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line seems to work. And a little messing with the jot size got the vertical space that I thought looked good. But of course, adjust it how you see fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation}
        \setlength{\jot}{5pt}
        \begin{split}
            \ch{ADP(aq) + P_i (aq) -> ATP(aq) + H2O (l)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (1)=30.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}} \\
            \ch{ADP(aq) + H2O (l) -> AMP(aq) + P_i (aq)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (2)=-28.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}} 
            \\[\jot] \hline \\[-2\jot]
            \ch{2 ADP(aq) -> AMP(aq) + ATP(aq)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (3)=2.0\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `siunitx` for the physical quantities.

With `alignedat` you can also set more alignment points. Using `siunitx` features, you can even squeeze the display in order to make room for the equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\ch{ADP(aq) + P_i (aq) & -> ATP(aq) + H2O (l)} & \qquad
  \Delta _r H^\circ _m (1) &= \qty{30.9}{kJ . mol^{-1}} \\
\ch{ADP(aq) + H2O (l) &-> AMP(aq) + P_i (aq)}  & \qquad
  \Delta _r H^\circ _m (2) &= \qty{-28.9}{kJ . mol^{-1}} \\
\midrule
\ch{2 ADP(aq) &-> AMP(aq) + ATP(aq)}           & \qquad
  \Delta _r H^\circ _m (3) &= \qty{2.0}{kJ . mol ^{-1}}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,fraction-command=\tfrac}
\addtolength{\aboverulesep}{\jot}
\addtolength{\belowrulesep}{\jot}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
\ch{ADP(aq) + P_i (aq) & -> ATP(aq) + H2O (l)} & \quad
  \Delta _r H^\circ _m (1) &= \qty{30.9}{\kilo\joule\per\mol} \\[0.5ex]
\ch{ADP(aq) + H2O (l) &-> AMP(aq) + P_i (aq)}  & \quad
  \Delta _r H^\circ _m (2) &= \qty{-28.9}{\kilo\joule\per\mol} \\
\midrule
\ch{2 ADP(aq) &-> AMP(aq) + ATP(aq)}           & \quad
  \Delta _r H^\circ _m (3) &= \qty{2.0}{\kilo\joule\per\mol}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \ch{ADP(aq) + P_i (aq) -> ATP(aq) + H2O (l)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (1)=30.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}} \\
    \ch{ADP(aq) + H2O (l) -> AMP(aq) + P_i (aq)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (2)=-28.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}} \\[-10pt]
    \underline{\phantom{\ch{ADP(aq) + H2O (l) -> AMP(aq) + P_i (aq)} \qquad}} &
      \underline{\phantom{\Delta _r H^\circ _m (2)=-28.9\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol^{-1}}}} \\
    \ch{2 ADP(aq) -> AMP(aq) + ATP(aq)} \qquad &\Delta _r H^\circ _m (3)=2.0\,\mathrm{kJ \cdot mol ^{-1}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array` can be handful in this case. Extra vertical spacing is usually achieved by adding custom struts.

There's also the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, which adds a lot of useful options to format quantities, numbers and units, or align values in tables (and arrays).

Here an example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength\rsep\setlength\rsep{9pt}
\newcommand\strutdw{\rule[-\rsep]{0pt}{\rsep}}
\newcommand\strutup{\rule[1.2ex]{0pt}{\rsep}}
\sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits = 1}
\DeclareSIUnit[
    inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\!\cdot\!}
]{\kjm}{\kJ\per\mol}


\begin{document}
\[
    \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.1}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \begin{array}{r @{\qquad} l}
        \ch{ADP(aq)} + \ch{P_i (aq)  -> ATP(aq) + H2O(l)}  &\Delta _r H^\circ_m (1) = \qty{30.9}{\kjm} \\
        \ch{ADP(aq)} + \ch{H2O (l)   -> AMP(aq) + P_i(aq)} &\Delta _r H^\circ_m (2) = \qty{-28.9}{\kjm}
        \strutdw \\ \hline
        \strutup
        \ch{2 ADP(aq) -> AMP(aq) + ATP(aq)} &\Delta _r H^\circ_m (3) = \qty{2}{\kjm}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```